# Three.js models are in bad quality

Tags: angular, three.js

I created an angular project with three.js, but when I load 3d models, they have a bad quality.

When I load this same models on this website : https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ they are perfect, in a great quality. I don't understand why. I tried to copy some of the open source code of this website, but this doesn't change anything :

I tried to load in gltf with that :

```
const loader = new GLTFLoader().setCrossOrigin('anonymous')
  .setDRACOLoader(new DRACOLoader().setDecoderPath('./wasm/'));
loader.load(
  'assets/Newblend3.glb',
  (gltf) => {
    gltf.scene.scale.set(200, 200, 200);
    this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
  },
  (xhr) => {
    console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log('An error happened');
  }
);
```

And in obj + mtl with that :

```
this.mtlLoader.load(await item?.mtl?.toUrl(), (materials) => {
  materials.preload();
  objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
  objLoader.load(item.objFile.url, (object) => {
    const mesh = object;
    this.scene.add(mesh);
  });
}, (i) => {
  console.log('Progress : ', i);
}, (e) => {
  console.log('Error : ', e);
});
```

But neither the first nor the second method works as I wanted :

On gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com :
[image]

On my angular app :

[image]

It's not just the lights, the threes are really more beatiful on the gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com version.

I've also a 404 error :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Jérémy.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Any 404's in the network tab?

Comment: Yes, I have one 404 error, but without any detail

Comment: What file is failing... a texture file maybe?

Comment: I don’t know, but I don’t think, it’s not a texture problem, it’s a shame problem (look at the pictures)

Comment: You're probably right, .. I'm not sure - but I would first have a look at what is causing the 404.

Comment: I edited my question to show you my error, but there is no more details

Comment: Lighting is a tricky process, it doesn't happen automatically. I recommend you add a hemisphereLight, directionalLight and Lambert materials [like in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_lights_hemisphere) if you want an illumination setup similar to Don McCourdy's.

Comment: I have already an hemisphere light. It’s not just a light problem , it’s a shape problem.

Comment: @JérémyGachon The screenshot above is either using an ambient light, which doesn't provide light/dark areas, or a hemisphere light with two equal colors, which also doesn't provide light/dark areas. The problem isn't the shapes or geometry, it's that your material is only showing a flat color. Have you tried assigning a `Lambert` material and a `DirectionalLight` like I suggested?

Comment: I've had similar problems that "magically" went away once I upgraded to a newer version of the GLTF loader (and three.js). Which versions are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewer you linked to adds lights where as the code you posted for your own viewer does not

Here's the code from the viewer

https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/src/viewer.js#L412

[MIT LICENSE](https://github.com/donmccurdy/three-gltf-viewer/blob/master/LICENSE)

```
  addLights () {
    const state = this.state;

    if (this.options.preset === Preset.ASSET_GENERATOR) {
      const hemiLight = new HemisphereLight();
      hemiLight.name = 'hemi_light';
      this.scene.add(hemiLight);
      this.lights.push(hemiLight);
      return;
    }

    const light1  = new AmbientLight(state.ambientColor, state.ambientIntensity);
    light1.name = 'ambient_light';
    this.defaultCamera.add( light1 );

    const light2  = new DirectionalLight(state.directColor, state.directIntensity);
    light2.position.set(0.5, 0, 0.866); // ~60º
    light2.name = 'main_light';
    this.defaultCamera.add( light2 );

    this.lights.push(light1, light2);
  }
```

The most important of those is the `DirectionalLight`. With it there will be no shading.

Example:

```css
html, body, canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; display: block; }
#info { position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px; color: white; }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<div id="info"></div>
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.module.js';
import {OrbitControls} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import {GLTFLoader} from 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js';

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(5, 10, 10);

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 2, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const lights = [];
  
  {
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 0.8 * Math.PI);
    light.position.set(50, 100, 20);
    scene.add(light.target);
    lights.push({name: 'DirectionalLight', light});
  }

  {
    const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    lights.push({name: 'AmbientLight', light});
  }

  {
    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffbb, 0x080820, 1);
    lights.push({name: 'HemisphereLight', light});
  }

  {
    const gltfLoader = new GLTFLoader();
    gltfLoader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/models/animals/Pig.gltf', (gltf) => {
      const root = gltf.scene;
      scene.add(root);
    });
  }

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }
  
  const infoElem = document.querySelector('#info');

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    const ndx = time % 3 | 0;
    lights.forEach(({name, light}, i) => {
      if (i == ndx) {
        if (!light.parent) { scene.add(light); infoElem.textContent = name; }
      } else {
        if (light.parent) { scene.remove(light); }
      }
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
</script>
```